# GCM Send to Sync message when users turns off the notification

Tags: android, performance, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to Android programming. Could you please help us understand what happens if my server sends a "ping" - Send to Sync GCM to a user (app) but user has turned off the notification for the app off in the mobile?

I have looked around but didn't find any. Perhaps, my search skill is fading away :)

Really appreciate people.

Cheers,
Raj

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is, the messages are not received as the device is offline. You need to put the ***collapse key***, ***timetolive***  along with ***delaywhileidle*** parameter in your app code to deal with such types of situations.

**Delay_while_idle**

If included, indicates that the message should not be sent immediately if the device is idle. The server will wait for the device to become active, and then only the last message for each collapse_key value will be sent.
Optional. The default value is false, and must be a JSON boolean.

**Time_to_live**

How long (in seconds) the message should be kept on GCM storage if the device is offline.
Optional Default time-to-live is 4 weeks/JSON value 2419200, and must be set as a JSON number.
If you use this parameter, you must also specify a collapse_key.

**Collapse_key**

An arbitrary string (such as "Updates Available") that is used to collapse a group of like messages when the device is offline, so that only the last message gets sent to the client. This is intended to avoid sending too many messages to the phone when it comes back online.
Note that since there is no guarantee of the order in which messages get sent, the "last" message may not actually be the last message sent by the application server. See Advanced Topics for more discussion of this topic.
Optional, unless you are using the time_to_live parameter then it is required.